# Changing Protocols affecting SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssl, tls1.2

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1.2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 are the only things I have enabled and I have disabled TSL 1.0 and SSL as seen below:

[image]

I have two instances of SQL Servers on my machine: `A 2008 SQL Express R2 and a SQL 2014`.

With those network settings I can still through SSMS connect to SQL 2014 but NOT to 2008 Express R2

So is that a known thing about SQL Servers? Can you explain what is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the server was not found, I think you did not use the correct server name, that is, if you have 2 instances, one of them is the default(I think 2014), the other one is a named instance, and if you didn't change the name offered by istallation the instance
 name is SQLExpress, so if you connect locally, you can use .\SQLExpress or localhost\SQLExpress or (local)\SQLExpress, if you connect remotely you should use yourCompName\SQLExpress and your SQL Server browser must be started (or you can use yourCompName,port_name instead and use no Browser)

Comment: You are correct but NO ! I used the correct name.  Same things I was using before disabled SSL and TLS 1.0

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1.2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: The kb article you mentioned enumerates some issues, but NONE of them gives an error that the server was not found. All the issues happen after the server was found, but refused the connection for one or another reason

Comment: Or may be your server was stopped and just cannot accept any connection?

Comment: Ok I checked services now, yes it was not running now. BUT I couldn't Start it either.  Maybe because of TSL ?

Comment: No the purpose of the article I posted is seeing what SQL Servers have TLS support. I couldn't find EXPRESS in there.  So Express not supported?

Comment: I apologise, I didn't ever use TLS, I just interpreted the error you've got. For troubleshooting why your server did not start first check the server errorlog

Comment: I wasn't aware of such a log file ... Look what I found there! pasted below:

The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x80090331. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.
Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The client and server cannot communicate

Comment: Yes, it definitely SSL, if you have a valid cerificate you should provide it using Configuration Manager: right click Protocols for Express, properties, certificate tab